# how can i fix "GameObject has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it" - unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am in process to make a 3D fps game with unity. But when i wrote the code to destroy the bullet after a particular time say - 5 seconds, till 5 seconds it spawnes the bullet and after 5 seconds the bullets spawned bullets get destroyed. But after that when i try to again spawn bullets, they dont get spawned and it shows the error GameObject has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
here is the destroy bullets code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using UnityEngine;

public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 8f;
    public Camera playerCamera;
    public float lifeDuration = 2f;
    private float lifeTimer;

    void Start()
    {
        lifeTimer =  lifeDuration;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position += playerCamera.transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
          
        lifeTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (lifeTimer <= 0f)
        {
            Destroy (gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: either don't destroy it or don't try to access it afterwards ;) Is it possible you try to use an actual existing GameObject from the scene for `Instantiate` and not a prefab living in the Assets? Could you post the actual error including stacktrace?

Comment: but the bullets need to be destroyed after some particular time they had spawned.

Comment: As said please add the complete error massage with stacktrace and all code that is possibly accessing the bullets (if you think that the bullets are the reason)

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when you try to access a gameobject which has been destroyed.

how do you spawn the bullet?

if it's a prefab,i suggest you do like this,and DO NOT call this gameobject in any other script after its "lifeTime":

```
var go = GameObject.Instantiate( Resources.Load( "bullet prefab path" ) ) as GameObject;
go.AddComponent<Bullet>();
```

if not, i think you're Instantiate a gameobject already exist in Hierarchy.

```
//if the "prefab" is already exist in Hierarchy with script "Bullet" and is active
//this "prefab" will be destroyed by your bullet script after "lifeTime"
//when the next time you Instantiate() with this "prefab"
//you'll get the error:"GameObject has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it"
GameObject go = GameObject.Instantiate(prefab) as GameObject;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that when you destroy the GO, the reference to that object may be lost too. In your case, in which you're using bullets, I recommend you to instead of using Destroy(gameObject), use gameObject.SetActive(false) and recycle the bullets with a pool of bullets that you instantiate at the start of the game. That way is easier to have a reference to the GO and optimize the cost of instantiating x bullets.